# What is the difference between +bbb and -bbb images in the 15.04 release?

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-core

In the stable 15.04 release [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/), there are two files for BeagleBoneBlack to download:
ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf+bbb.img.xz and
ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img.xz

They have the same size, but the checksums [differ](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/MD5SUMS). In the [official manual](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#try-beaglebone), the -bbb image is mentioned. What is the difference between the two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between the two except for the filename. One is 'armhf+bbb', the other is 'armhf-bbb', and one is a symlink
to the other on the server.  The reason we have both names is that we had
pushed one of these names as the URL to publish on the website, then
realized that the name we'd pushed was inconsistent with the overall naming
scheme on releases.ubuntu.com.

Comment: +1 for likely notable answer, because this was answered by the Product Manager of Snappy Ubuntu.